# How to transpose multiple rows and columns with orders to columns with number order of order and products?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas

I have a table in Google Spreadsheet from API with data of order and products

[image]

I have number of orders with data of products inside table

```
order number1 | sku1 | name1 | qty1 | sku2 | name2 | qty2 | sku3 | name3 | qty3 |

order number2 | sku1 | name1 | qty1 | sku2 | name2 | qty2

order number3 | sku1 | name1 | qty1 | sku2 | name2 | qty2 | ... |sku15 | name15 | qty15`
```

I want to receive table for my stock with data

```
_____________________________________
order number1 | sku1 | name1 | qty1 |
              | sku2 | name2 | qty2 |
______________| sku3 | name3 | qty3 |
order number2 | sku1 | name1 | qty1 |
______________| sku2 | name2 | qty2 |
order number3 | sku1 | name1 | qty1 |
              | ...  |  ...  | ...  |
              | sku15| name15| qty15|
```

Using `=ARRAYFORMULA`

and `=TRANSPOSE`

How to do it?

Comment: Put examples in blocks of code to improve readability.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output